# develop android game - canvas or opengl, for specific kind of game

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-canvas

I want to develop an adroid game.

I want to develop a simple game in 2D, like these games:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.dirtybit.funrun&hl=en
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sagego.panda.run&hl=en

I know how to design characters and other objects for this kind of game.

Can I use android canvas class in order to develop a game like the examples above?
I read that the canvas class is now hardware accelerated.
or I have to learn the hard way - openGL ?

Comment: You can use some game-engine like the [Andengine](http://www.andengine.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I would try using Unity, if you still don't have good android skills, because it's more visual than code writing.

Other alternatives are LibGDX or AndEngine, with a lot of tutorials and active community out there, as they have Apache 2 License, unlike Unity thats not completely free.

Comment: I don't want to use an open source library because I won't be able to sell my game later

Answer (score 0):

AndEngine has a little learning curve as you know Java and basic Android already.

Answer (score 0):

As you never developed a game before I suggest you to try something really simple at first.

Here is some inspiration : http://inventwithpython.com/blog/2012/02/20/i-need-practice-programming-49-ideas-for-game-clones-to-code/comment-page-1/

A good exercise would be to try to make it first with the canvas, then port it to a game engine or even opengl.

Comment: how can I port canvas game to opengl .. ? does canvas similar to opengl ? it's not something completely different?